# Sed conditional match and execute command with offset

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I am finding a bash command for a conditional replacement with offset.  The existing posts that I've found are conditional replacement *without* offset or with a *fixed* offset.

Task: If `uid` contains `8964`, then insert the line `FORBIDDEN` before `DOB`.

Each TXT file below represents one user, and it contains (in the following order)

1. *some* property(ies)
2. *unique* `uid`
3. *some* quality(ies)
4. *unique* `DOB`
5. a random *lorem ipsum*

I hope I can transform the following files

```
# file1.txt (uid doens't match 8964)
admin: false
uid: 123456
happy
movie
DOB: 6543-02-10
lorem ipsum
seo varis lireccuni paccem noba sako

# file2.txt (uid matches 8964)
citizen: true
hasSEAcct: true
uid: 289641
joyful hearty
final debug Juno XYus
magazine
DOB: 1234-05-06
saadi torem lopez dupont
```

into

```
# file1.txt (uid doens't match 8964)
admin: false
uid: 123456
happy
movie
DOB: 6543-02-10
lorem ipsum
seo varis lireccuni paccem noba sako

# file2.txt (uid matches 8964)
citizen: true
hasSEAcct: true
uid: 289641
joyful hearty
final debug Juno XYus
magazine
FORBIDDEN
DOB: 1234-05-06
saadi torem lopez dupont
```

My try:

If `uid` contains `8964`, then do a 2nd match with `DOB`, and insert `FORBIDDEN` above `DOB`.

```
sed '/^uid: [0-9]*8964[0-9]*$/{n;/^DOB: .*$/{iFORBIDDEN}}' file*.txt
```

This gives me an unmatched `{` error.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'
```

I know that `sed '/PAT/{n;p}'` will execute `{n;p}` if `PAT` is matched, but it seems impossible to put `/PAT2/{iTEXT}` inside `/PAT/{  }`.

How can I perform such `FORBIDDEN` insertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '
  /^uid/ && /8964/ {f=1}                     #1
  /^DOB/ && f {print "FORBIDDEN"; f=0}       #2
  1                                          #3
' file
```

1. If a line starting with "uid" matches "8964", set flag
2. If a line starts with "DOB" and flag is set, print string and unset flag
3. print every line

```
$ awk -v RS='' '/uid: [0-9]*8964/{sub(/DOB/, "FORBIDDEN\nDOB")} 1' file
```

Alternatively, treat every block separated by a blank line as a single record, then sub in "FORBIDDEN\nDOB" if there's a match. I think the first one's better practice. As a very general rule, once you start thinking in terms of fields/records, it's time for awk/perl.

Comment: Thanks for answer.  It really works.  However, I *don't* know `awk`.  Where can I learn the basics?  I _can't_ find "flag" in [this famous `awk` tutorial](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).  Why `FORBIDDEN` is printed _before_ `DOB` and not _after_?  I tried replacing `1` with `2` or `0.5` at line `#3`.  What does `1` mean?

Comment: Don't be intimidated, it's just the next level up from Sed. Awk is also valuable as a teaching tool for `C` logic, so read `man gawk`. `1` (or more) is true, while `0` (or null) is false. "flag" isn't an official term, just the idea of a boolean variable that we turn "on" or "off" to keep tabs on a condition. When there's a condition with no `{action}`, like `1` all by itself, awk does the default behavior, which is `{print $0}` (print the whole line).

Comment: Thanks for response.  I've gone through `man awk` on Ubuntu, and have a better idea about `mawk`.  If I swap `#2` and `#3`, I get `FORBIDDEN` _after_ `DOB`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is a good use-case for sed.

Here is a GNU sed solution with some explanation:

```sed
# script.sed
/^uid:.*8964/,/DOB/ { # Search only inside this range, if it exists.
  /DOB/i FORBIDDEN    # Insert FORBIDDEN before the line matching /DOB/.
}
```

Testing:

```
▶ gsed -f script.sed FILE2 
citizen: true
hasSEAcct: true
uid: 289641
joyful hearty
final debug Juno XYus
magazine
FORBIDDEN
DOB: 1234-05-06
saadi torem lopez dupont
```

```
▶ gsed -f script.sed FILE1
admin: false
uid: 123456
happy
movie
DOB: 6543-02-10
lorem ipsum
seo varis lireccuni paccem noba sako
```

Or on one line:

```
▶ gsed -e '/^uid:.*8964/,/DOB/{/DOB/i FORBIDDEN' -e '}' FILE*
```

Comment: Nice answer!  Regarding the one-line command, is there a reason for such separation?  I only know that if the three expression are put together, there will be an unmatched `{` error.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會, and nice question too by the way. The multiple `-e`s are there because the `i` command expects "lines" of text to follow. AFAIK, the string to insert must be followed by a newline character, but the `}` still needs to close the `{` .. `}` block. So I don't know any other way to put it all on one line than to use multiple `-e`s.

Comment: See also the examples here https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands

Answer (score 1):

tried on gnu sed

```
 sed -Ee '/^uid:\s*\w*8964\w*$/{n;/^DOB:/iFORBIDDEN' -e '}' file*.txt
```